# pandas Count column, where value is yes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe table like this

| First name | First name | Parameter 1 | Parameter 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | No | No |
| 1 | 1 | Yes | No |
| 1 | 1 | Yes | No |

I need to count all rows where column `Parameter 1` AND `Parameter 2` is `Yes`

I use pandas for this, but is doesn't work.

`Temp.append(list(df.loc[(df.Parameter1 == 'Yes') & (df.Parameter2== 'Yes')].count()))`

Error: `Cannot index with multidimensional key`

How i can solve this problem?

Comment: just count number of rows? use len? `len(df.loc[(df.Parameter1 == 'Yes') & (df.Parameter2== 'Yes')])`

Comment: Or just `((df.Parameter1 == 'Yes') & (df.Parameter2== 'Yes')).sum()`

Comment: `Cannot index with multidimensional key`

Answer (score 3):

You can ask if a condition is satisfied for multiple columns and then check that is always satisfied in each row.

```py
import pandas as pd

# data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"id": [0,1,2,3],
     "par1":["Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"],
     "par2":["Yes", "No", "Yes", "No"]})

# count how many times both par are Yes
df[["par1", "par2"]].eq("Yes").all(1).sum()
```

Comment: And if I want to count the number of rows where par1 = "yes" and par2= "not"? How can this be solved?

Comment: @СергейКорягин this is a different case than the original question. You should ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[(df['Parameter 1'] == 'Yes') & (df['Parameter 2'] == 'Yes')].sum()
```

Comment: `Cannot index with multidimensional key`

Comment: If you have such a problem I'd suggest you to share `df.head().to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

loc only accepts scalar (for single index) / tuple (for multi index) or list like data structure as labels, not dataframe. Make sure your index is not a data frame. If it’s a data frame, convert it to a Series object first by simply accessing the column that you want to use as index.

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
sum((temp['Parameter 1'] == 'Yes') & (temp['Parameter 1'] == 'Yes'))
```